# Como extraer filas con cierto nombre de varios archivos excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Tengo el siguiente data frame: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual necesito extraer ciertas filas especificas en mi codigo, pero me surge el siguiente error : KeyError: "None of ['CONFIGURACIÓN'] are in the columns"

Este es mi codigo:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import sys


all_files = glob.glob("C:/Users/ep_irojaso/Desktop/PROGRAMA DESEMPEÑO/PRG/*.xlsx")

file_list = []
for f in (all_files):   
    data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name='Reservas CPF - Conf', header=0)
    data.set_index("CONFIGURACIÓN",inplace = True)
    
    data.loc[["CANDELARIA-1_DIESEL", "CANDELARIA-1_GN_A", "CANDELARIA-1_GNL_A", "CANDELARIA-1_GNL_B", "CANDELARIA-1_GNL_C", "CANDELARIA-1_GNL_D", "CANDELARIA-1_GNL_E", "CANDELARIA-1_GNL_F", "CANDELARIA-1_GNL_G", "CANDELARIA-1_GNL_INFLEX", "CANDELARIA-2_DIESEL", "CANDELARIA-2_GN_A", "CANDELARIA-2_GNL_A", "CANDELARIA-2_GNL_B", "CANDELARIA-2_GNL_C", "CANDELARIA-2_GNL_D", "CANDELARIA-2_GNL_E", "CANDELARIA-2_GNL_F", "CANDELARIA-2_GNL_G", "CANDELARIA-2_GNL_INFLEX", "COLBUN-1", "COLBUN-2", "ANGOSTURA-1", "ANGOSTURA-2", "ANGOSTURA-3", "CANUTILLAR-1", "CANUTILLAR-2"]].to_excel(f'C:/Users/ep_irojaso/Desktop/PROGRAMA DESEMPEÑO/PRGred/{os.path.basename(f).split(".")[0]}_final.xlsx',index=False)
```

Comment: Me suena que el error puede ser las filas que tienes antes de la tabla, puedes usar `header=3` para saltarte los que no tienen información

Comment: me funciono con header=4, pero no aparecen los nombres de las filas como "CANDELARIA", etc